# Android, Handling multiple URL for parsing

Tags: android

I am making a simple news reader app. The news need to be shown in one RecyclerView, like a list of news. The problem is that there are a multiple URLs from whom i extract data and i know only how to parse one but dont know how to handle more of them. Here is my code:

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = NewsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String newsUrl1 = "http://tests.intellex.rs/api/v1/news/list?page=1";
    public static final String newsUrl2 = "http://tests.intellex.rs/api/v1/news/list?page=2";
    public static final String newsUrl3 = "http://tests.intellex.rs/api/v1/news/list?page=3";
    public static final String newsUrl4 = "http://tests.intellex.rs/api/v1/news/list?page=4";

    private NewsAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<NewsModel> newsArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_news_recycler_view__);

        newsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(this, newsArray);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.newsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext()));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        NewsAsyncTask task = new NewsAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
    }
    private class NewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<NewsModel>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<NewsModel> doInBackground(URL... urls) {

            URL url = createUrl(newsUrl1);
            String jsonResponse = "";
            try {
                jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);
        }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<NewsModel> news) {
            if (news == null) {
                return;
            }
            adapter.addAll(news);
        }
        private URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(stringUrl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL", exception);
                return null;
            }
            return url;
        }

        private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
            String jsonResponse = "";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                urlConnection.connect();

                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the JSON results.", e);
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    output.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        private ArrayList<NewsModel> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJson) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJson)) {
                return null;
            }
            ArrayList<NewsModel> news_information = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJson);
                JSONArray newsArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("list");
                for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject news = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    try {
                        news = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String newsImage = news.getString("image");
                        String newsTitle = news.getString("title");
                        String newsPublished = news.getString("published");
                        String newsAuthor = news.getString("author");
                        String newsID = news.getString("id");

                        NewsModel newsModel = new NewsModel(newsImage, newsTitle, newsPublished, newsAuthor, newsID);
                        news_information.add(newsModel);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return news_information;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that the only difference in the URLs in your code is the page numbers. So what you need is to display the news from the subsequent pages. Take a look at this question to see how it's implemented with AsyncTask: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42854142/2688283. However, I recommend using Retrofit instead and you can find info on how to set it up here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ and here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "links" as array  ?
In case you will use an array:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray keys = jsonObject.getJSONArray("links");
int length = keys.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    new ReadJSON().execute(keys.getString(i));
}
```

Anyway, you take all the keys and go one after the other, and then query each
EDIT:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(/*Your links json*/);
JSONObject links = jsonObject.get("links");
Iterator<String> keys = links.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    new ReadJSON().execute(links.getString(keys.next()));
}
```

Comment: I saw this in Udacity tutorial and i am relatively new to programing. That solution of yours, where i need to write that?